# From Binary Search to 3-ary Search

Tags: java, algorithm

The reason because a 3-ary Search is less convenient than a Binary Search is because at every call a 3-ary Search needs to do two confronts, while a Binary Search only one: thus 3-ary costs 2log<sub>3</sub>(n) and Binary log<sub>2</sub>(n). That is a known fact.

I had an idea.

There is an algorithm called *Ternary Search* that allows to find the maximum of a function *f* upon an array, provided that maximum to be the only one. Below is the Java code:

```
    public static <T> int ternarySearch(T[] array, Function<T,Double> f){
        int l = 0, r = array.length,
                m1 = l + (r-l)/3,
                m2 = r - (r-l)/3,
                valutation;
        while( m1 != m2 )
            {
            valutation = f.apply(array[m1]).compareTo(f.apply(array[m2]));
            switch(valutation)
                {
                case -1:    {   r = m1;                 m1 = l + (r-l)/3;   m2 = r - (r-l)/3;   break;  }
                case  0:    {   l = m1;     r = m2;     m1 = l + (r-l)/3;   m2 = r - (r-l)/3;   break;  }
                case  1:    {   l = m2;                 m1 = l + (r-l)/3;   m2 = r - (r-l)/3;   break;  }
                }
            }       
        return m1;
    }
```

**If** we can find a function that has as only maximum a choosen `key` and **if** the method `compareTo()` costs as only *one* confront between numbers, a call of `ternarySearch(array, f)` would costs only log<sub>3</sub>(n): less than the Binary Search.

Now, my questions are:

1. How can we choose such a function `f`?
2. Does the method `compareTo()` cost as only *one* confront between numbers?
3. Is my idea correct?

Answer (score 0):

Answers:

1. Just use identity function `f(x) = x` to simplify things - Trying to find functions to best fit the values would reduce applicability of this search by a lot; identity function and not decreasing values (sorted) array are good starting point
2. No, it costs **2** (see below)
3. I don't think so, for the reasons listed below:

Here are few pointers:

- *Ternary Search* has potential to filter more numbers out (2/3 out instead of 1/2) but only 1/3 of the time (and 2/3 of the time it filters 1/3rd of the space) and it does **indeed require 1 more comparison** than *Binary Search* even when using `Integer.compareTo()`.
  Please check the [source code for `Integer.compareTo()` to see 2 comparisons happening.](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Integer.java#Integer.compareTo%28java.lang.Integer%29)
- Following your train of thought, we should be going up with **N** to achieve **N-ary** searches performing better than *Binary Search* with diminishing returns for growing **N**s as the number of comparisons would also be **N**
- Please see few answers on [to the similar question on CS Stack Exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/29755/why-is-binary-search-faster-than-ternary-search)